# Related to Angular Routes(single page application)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Would like someone to help me in front end UI routing using angularjs?
Am designing login & register setup but routing is not working perfectly and also bootstrap rendering does not render it properly when connected via MVC structure..

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UI-ROUTER` for routing in angular js.

**UI-Router applications are modelled as a hierarchical tree of states. UI-Router provides a state machine to manage the transitions between those application states in a transaction-like manner.**

Here is an example route configuration,

```
$stateProvider
    .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'registerController'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/logn',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
    })
    // nested list with custom controller
    .state('home.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
        }
    })
    // nested list with just some random string data
    .state('home.paragraph', {
        url: '/paragraph',
        template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
})
```

[Github link for documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

[Another reference for ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/)

[**A Demo for routing and navigation using ui-router**](http://embed.plnkr.co/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7/preview)